# does "transition:all" include the "transition:transform"?

Tags: css-transitions

I can see the `css` property list does not has `transform`.so does `transition:all` include the `transition:transform`?and how do I test that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  Doing a quick search leads me to the menu on:

http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/css-animation/#section_2